# How do I set the value of a cell to be the same as the value of another cell inside an IF statement?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I want to set the value of a cell to be the same as the value of another cell if that cell is not blank.
    =IF(INDIRECT(C2)!="",B2=INDIRECT(C2))
Any ideas on why this doesn't work or how to make it work?
Thanks

Comment: You should take out the B2= and this formula should be in B2

Comment: But sometimes B2 will contain content, so I can't place this formula inside that cell

Comment: You can't create a formula that will change the content of a cell from outside of that cell.

Comment: Really?  That seems like an odd limitation (although it would explain my difficulty in finding a solution)

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDIRECT(C2)), "Bad Reference", INDIRECT(C2))
```

Basically `ISERROR(INDIRECT(C2))` is true if C2 is blank or an invalid cell reference. When it is true, put `"Bad Reference"` into this cell, when there is no error, put `INDIRECT(C2)` into this cell.

Comment: The iferror function could also be usefull in your example: `=IFERROR(INDIRECT(C2),"Bad Reference") ` does exactly the same